# i have a controller mapping issue while running two controller together

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

I have two controllers one for login through database and one for inserting values in the database in spring java.I have an error of mapping them.How to map those two controllers during execution.The error tells tells that it has some reference problem. When i run only login controller than it works fine but as soon as i add my registration controller to it fails. Actually registration controller is needed after login.

```
enter code here
package com.login.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.login.bean.BorewellBean;
import com.login.delegate.BorewellDelegate;
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value ="/fillup")
@Component
public class BorewellController {

@Autowired
private BorewellDelegate borewelldelegate;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView fillup(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse     response)
{
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("loginsuccess");
    BorewellBean bean=new BorewellBean();
    model.addObject("bean",bean);
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST )
public ModelAndView executefillup(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,@ModelAttribute("bean")BorewellBean bean)
{   

    ModelAndView model=null;
    try{
        boolean isValidUser=borewelldelegate.setvalue(bean.getBid(),bean.getDate(),bean.getStart(),bean.getStop());
                if(isValidUser)
                {
                    System.out.println("entry done");
                    request.setAttribute("bid",bean.getBid());
                    model=new ModelAndView("welcome");
                }
                else
                {
                    model=new ModelAndView("loginsuccess"); 
                }       
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
    return model;


}
}
```

LoginController.java

```
enter code here
package com.login.controller;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.login.bean.BorewellBean;
import com.login.bean.LoginBean;
import com.login.delegate.BorewellDelegate;
import com.login.delegate.LoginDelegate;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/loginform")
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private LoginDelegate loginDelegate;


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showLogin(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
{
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("login");
    LoginBean loginbean= new LoginBean();
    model.addObject("loginBean",loginbean);
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView executeLogin(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,@ModelAttribute("loginBean")LoginBean loginBean)
{   
    ModelAndView model=null;
    try{
        boolean isValidUser=loginDelegate.isValidUser(loginBean.getUsername(),loginBean.getPassword());
                if(isValidUser)
                {
                    System.out.println("Login successful");
                    request.setAttribute("loginUser",loginBean.getUsername());


                    model=new ModelAndView("loginsuccess");
                }
                else
                {
                    model=new ModelAndView("login");    
                }       
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
    return model;

}
 }



SpringBeanConfiguration.xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="loginDelegate" class="com.login.delegate.LoginDelegate">
    <property name="loginservice" ref="userService"></property>
 </bean>

<bean id="userService" class="com.login.service.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"></property>
</bean>

<bean name="userDao" class="com.login.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

 <bean id="borewelldelegate" class="com.login.delegate.BorewellDelegate">
    <property name="borewellservice" ref="borewellserviceimpl">     </property>
</bean>

<bean id="borewellserviceimpl" class="com.login.service.Borewellimpl" >
    <property name="borewelldao" ref="borewelldao"></property>
</bean>

<bean name="borewelldao" class="com.login.dao.Borewelldaoimpl" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>  

<bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
 <property name="password" value="rat" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

> my error  HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw  exception
>   Error creating bean with name 'borewellserviceimpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.login.dao.Borewelldao com.login.service.Borewellimpl.borewelldao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.login.dao.Borewelldao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:  {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   Login.jsp
>       enter code here

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form  action="loginform.html"  modelAttribute="loginBean" > 
<table>
<tr>
<td>User Name:<FONT color="red"><form:errors path="username" /></FONT>      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:input path="username" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:<FONT color="red"><form:errors path="password" /></FONT>   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:password path="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you try to map the same url path? It's hard to say without seeing your code

Comment: Or show us the error

Comment: add your both controller class

Comment: @michalsol my code is right up there.

Comment: are you using MVC pattern?

Comment: @Manihtraa yes i am using mvc pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use @Service in your service implemented class and in Dao layer must use @Repository in all DAO class

Comment: i have used it in my all classes above annotations. But the error is same.should i use @Autowired annotation also.

Comment: No need to use Autowired annotation in above the class. also if you use annotations service,Reposiory means no need to create bean in SpringBeanConfiguration.xml so remove that.